# Problem with joint PDF of two random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm going through probability problems for an upcoming exam and came across this problem:

> The PDF of the random vector $(X,Y)$ is $f(x,y)=3\min\left\{x,y\right\}, 0<x,y<1$. If the random variable $Z$ is defined as $Z=\max\{X,Y\}$, calculate the coefficient of correlation between $X$ and $Z$.

Most of the stuff needed is easy enough to work out, but to get $E[XZ]$ the approach I took is to find the joint CDF of $X$ and $Z$, which I worked out to be $F_{X,Z}(x,z)=\frac{3}{2}x^2z-\frac{1}{2}x^3$ for $0<x<z<1$ and functions of only one variable in other cases. This would mean that if there's a PDF, it would have to be $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial z}F_{X,Z}(x,z)$, i.e., $f_{X,Z}(x,z)=3x$ for $0<x<z<1$ and $0$ otherwise. However, this function can't be a PDF since its integral over $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not $1$.

So my questions are: Is this correct? If so, what other approach can I take to find $E[XZ]$?

Comment: $f(x,y)=3\min\left\{x,y\right\}, 0<x,y<1$ is it your PDF $3$ times $\min({x,y})$?

Comment: @Daman sorry, I don't quite understand your question

Comment: Your pdf has $3\cdot \min(x,y)$ ? How do you integerate it to $1$?

Comment: @Daman Just regular integration over $R^2$ (or rather $(0,1)^2$). I don't see an issue with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no pdf of $(X,Z)$ under Lebesgue measure since $X=Z$ holds with positive probability.

You have $$XZ=\begin{cases} X^2 &,\text{ if }X\ge Y \\ XY &, \text{ if }X<Y \end{cases}$$

If $\mathbf1$ is an indicator variable, then by law of total expectation $$\operatorname E\left[XZ\right]=\operatorname E\left[X^2\mathbf1_{X\ge Y}\right]+\operatorname E\left[XY\mathbf1_{X<Y}\right]$$

To calculate $\operatorname E\left[g(X,Y)\right]$ for any (measurable) function $g(\cdot)$, use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) theorem:

$$\operatorname E\left[g(X,Y)\right]=\iint g(x,y)f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y$$

So for example,

\begin{align}
\operatorname E\left[X^2\mathbf1_{X\ge Y}\right]&=3\iint x^2\mathbf1_{x\ge y}\min(x,y)\mathbf1_{0<x,y<1}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y
\\&=3\iint x^2y\,\mathbf1_{0<y\le x<1}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y
\\&=3\int_0^1 y\int_y^1 x^2\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y
\end{align}

Comment: Ah right, didn't think to split XZ like that. Thank you!

Comment: Actually this is simpler than that:

$$\operatorname E\left[XZ\right]=3\iint x\max(x,y)\min(x,y)\mathbf1_{0<x,y<1}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y=3\int_0^1 x^2\,\mathrm{d}x\int_0^1 y\,\mathrm{d}y$$ No need to split $XZ$ since $\max(x,y)\min(x,y)=xy$.